# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).findOne is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typeerror

When trying to call getStocks from a Vue component I get the error stated above.

smileCalc:

```
import User from "../models/user.js";

let userID = "62e6d96a51186be0ad2864f9";
let userStocks;

async function getUserStocks() {
    await User.findOne({ _id: userID }, (err, user) => {
        if (user != null || user != undefined) {
            userStocks = user.stocks;
        }
    }).clone();
};

export async function getStocks() {
    await getUserStocks();
    return userStocks;
}
```

Vue Component:

```
<script>
import { getStocks } from "../../../backend/scripts/smileCalc.js";

export default {
    methods: {
        getStocks,
    },
};
</script>

<template>
    <h1>User Stocks: {{ getStocks() }}</h1>
</template>
```

I know that the Schema is defined, exported, and imported correctly because I do not get the error when I execute the script and it works normally. The solution that I have found for TypeErrors similar to mine is to add a semicolon to the end of the function, but that did not fix my issue. I also tried using findById rather than findOne and got the same error.

Comment: Can you show you export `User` from `user.js`? Just the export part.

Comment: and that the exported thing provides or inherits `findOne`

Comment: ```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const user = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        stocks: [],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
export default mongoose.model("User", user); 
``` It won't let me put it into markdown, I'm sorry

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Is this server-side or in the browser? (Are you trying to access MongoDB from browser JavaScript?)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to access the contents of an array thats in a users schema and get it displayed onto the browser using a Vue component

Answer (score 1):

Update: The issue I was having was trying to access my mongoose schema on the client side which was hosted on port 3000 while my backend was being hosted on 4000. I needed to implement an HTTP request to interact between the two.